# model method rails syntax

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model

I'm trying to write a method to return true or false whether a product is actually in stock in a particular storage. I want to pass storage as parameter but receive an error through the console. What's the right syntax?

```
def units_in_stock(storage)
  storage_id = Storage.find_by_id(storage)
  stocks.where("stock.storage_id = storage_id, in_stock > 0")
end
```

Comment: In general, when something gives an error, you'd want to tell us what the error is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be:

```
where("stock.storage_id=? and in_stock>0", storage_id)
```

You could also use `conditions`.

Comment: Thanks. Works like a charm. Just needed to remove the extra stock so the correct syntax in my case is `where("storage_id=? and in_stock>0", storage_id)`

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me that you are passing in a Storage object so you should be able to do something like this:

```
def units_in_stock?(storage)
  storage.stocks.where("in_stock > 0").exists?
end
```